# Bootloader with text and graphics ...howto ?( with nasm )

Tags: nasm, bootloader

Below i have a code that draw 3 circles in 3 different colors.. that is fine..
but how do i addmit a text string ? Thx.
I did some tests on virtualbox (windows), but no luck..
Any ideas to get it worked ?.

```html
BITS 16
ORG 100h

push 0a000h           ;Video memory graphics segment
pop es

mov ax, 0013h         ;320x200@8bpp
int 10h


push 0Eh              ;Blue
push 10               ;cX
push 10               ;cY
push 10               ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle

push 02h              ;Blue
push 40               ;cX
push 40               ;cY
push 30               ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle

push 06h              ;Blue
push 140              ;cX
push 100              ;cY
push 70               ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle



;Wait for a key
xor ah, ah
int 16h
loc   db "KERNEL  IMG"

.LOOP:
          push    cx
          mov     cx, 0x000B                          ; eleven character name
          mov     si, loc
          ; image name to find
          push    di
     rep  cmpsb                                       ; test for entry match
          pop     di
          ;je      LOAD_FAT
          pop     cx
          add     di, 0x0020                          ; queue next directory entry
          loop    .LOOP
          ;jmp     FAILURE
;Restore text mode
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h

;Return
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


;Color
;cX
;cY
;R
drawFilledCircle:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 sub sp, 02h

 mov cx, WORD [bp+04h]   ;R

 mov ax, cx              
 mul ax                  ;AX = R^2
 mov WORD [bp-02h], ax   ;[bp-02h] = R^2



 mov ax, WORD [bp+06h]
 sub ax, cx              ;i = cY-R
 mov bx, WORD [bp+08h]
 sub bx, cx              ;j = cX-R

 shl cx, 1
 mov dx, cx              ;DX = Copy of 2R

.advance_v:
 push cx
 push bx

 mov cx,  dx

.advance_h:
  ;Save values
  push bx
  push ax
  push dx

  ;Compute (i-y) and (j-x)
  sub ax, WORD [bp+06h]
  sub bx, WORD [bp+08h]

  mul ax                  ;Compute (i-y)^2

  push ax
  mov ax, bx             
  mul ax
  pop bx                  ;Compute (j-x)^2 in ax, (i-y)^2 is in bx now

  add ax, bx              ;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2
  cmp ax, WORD [bp-02h]   ;;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 <= R^2

  ;Restore values before jump
  pop dx
  pop ax
  pop bx

  ja .continue            ;Skip pixel if (j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 > R^2

  ;Write pixel
  push WORD [bp+0ah]
  push bx
  push ax
  call writePx


.continue:

  ;Advance j
  inc bx
 loop .advance_h

 ;Advance i
 inc ax


 pop bx            ;Restore j
 pop cx            ;Restore counter

loop .advance_v

 add sp, 02h


 pop bp
 ret 08h



;Color
;X
;Y
writePx:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 push ax
 push bx

 mov bx, WORD [bp+04h]
 mov ax, bx
 shl bx, 6
 shl ax, 8
 add bx, ax       ;320 = 256 + 64

 add bx, WORD [bp+06h]
 mov ax, WORD [bp+08h]

 ;TODO: Clip

 mov BYTE [es:bx], al

 pop bx
 pop ax

 pop bp
 ret 06h





times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; Fill the rest with zeros
dw 0xAA55  ; Boot loader signature
```

Comment: You say this is a bootloader (and you have a bootloader signature at the end), but i'm confused by the fact you have `ORG 100h` . That org would be normal for a DOS COM program.

Comment: Typically most bootloaders use `ORG 0x7c00` or `ORG 0x0000` and then set the _DS_ register accordingly to start the bootloader. If you used `ORG 0x0000` you'd have to set _DS_ to 0x07c0, if you use `ORG 0x7c00` you'd set _DS_ to 0x0000. 0x07c0:0000 and 0x0000:0x7c00 both map to the same physical address 0x07c00 where the bootloader is loaded into memory by the BIOS.

Comment: You've placed `loc   db "KERNEL  IMG"` after `int 16h` so it will be executed as code after int 16h is complete. Place the variables in your code after the last of the code and before the boot signature to avoid that problem.

Comment: A bootloader can't use DOS interrupts (It is limited to BIOS interrupts) so this call won't work as expected `mov ax, 4c00h` `int 21h`. A bootloader often ends by putting a processor in a HLT state by doing `CLI` followed by `HLT`.

Comment: So I guess the first question is. Are you creating a DOS COM program, or are you creating a bootloader?

Comment: I don't believe the BIOS routines allows you to output text in a graphics mode like 320x200. If you are trying to mix text and graphics on the same screen you would likely have to render the characters yourself.

Comment: Hi, thx for your time to look at the code.I try to make a bootloader.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Even in a graphics mode like 320x200 can you use the BIOS routines for text output, albeit _restricted_ to the character cell positions. You would only have to render the characters yourself if a pixel accurate position was needed.

Answer (score 1):

> but how do i addmit a text string ?

You've decided to use the 320x200 256 colors video mode 13h.
To output text you can use every BIOS function that deals with text output, just like you would do on a text video screen.

This video mode uses an 8x8 font and so you can position the cursor at any of the 40x25=1000 character cells.

Example of writing a red colored capital **B** at the center of the screen:

```
mov dx, 0C14h  ;DH=12  row,               DL=20 column
mov bh, 0      ;BH=0   display page
mov ah, 02h    ;AH=02h set cursor position function
int 10h        ;video BIOS interrupt

mov bx, 000Ch  ;BH=0   display page,      BL=12 red
mov ax, 0E42h  ;AH=0Eh teletype function, AL=66 capital B
int 10h        ;video BIOS interrupt
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
BITS 16

[ORG 0x7C00]




;ORG 100h

 

push 0a000h           ;Video memory graphics segment
pop es

mov ax, 0013h         ;320x200@8bpp
int 10h


push 0Eh              ;Blue
push 10              ;cX
push 10               ;cY
push 10          ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle

push 02h              ;Blue
push 40              ;cX
push 40               ;cY
push 30           ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle

push 06h              ;Blue
push 140              ;cX
push 100               ;cY
push 70           ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle




;Wait for a key
;xor ah, ah
;int 16h

 


main:  ; Label for the start of the main program

 mov ax,0x0000 ; Setup the Data Segment register
  ; Location of data is DS:Offset
 mov ds,ax ; This can not be loaded directly it has to be in two steps.
  ; 'mov ds, 0x0000' will NOT work due to limitations on the CPU

 mov si, HelloWorld ; Load the string into position for the procedure.


 call PutStr ; Call/start the procedure






;jmp $  ; Never ending loop

; Procedures
PutStr:  ; Procedure label/start
 ; Set up the registers for the interrupt call
 mov ah,0x0E ; The function to display a chacter (teletype)
 mov bh,0x00 ; Page number
 mov bl,0x07 ; Normal text attribute

.nextchar ; Internal label (needed to loop round for the next character)
 lodsb  ; I think of this as LOaD String Block 
  ; (Not sure if thats the real meaning though)
  ; Loads [SI] into AL and increases SI by one
 ; Check for end of string '0' 
 or al,al ; Sets the zero flag if al = 0 
  ; (OR outputs 0's where there is a zero bit in the register)
 jz .return ; If the zero flag has been set go to the end of the procedure.
  ; Zero flag gets set when an instruction returns 0 as the answer.
 int 0x10 ; Run the BIOS video interrupt 
 jmp .nextchar ; Loop back round tothe top
.return  ; Label at the end to jump to when complete
; ret  ; Return to main program
;Wait for a key
xor ah, ah
int 16h

push 01h              ;Blue
push 100              ;cX
push 90               ;cY
push 140           ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle


;ret
; Data

HelloWorld db '   WELCOME !!   Press Enter ',10,10,0



 loc   db "KERNEL  IMG"

.LOOP:
          push    cx
          mov     cx, 0x000B                          ; eleven character name
          mov     si, loc
                       ; image name to find
          push    di
     rep  cmpsb                                       ; test for entry match
          pop     di
          ;je      LOAD_FAT
          pop     cx
          add     di, 0x0020                          ; queue next directory entry
          loop    .LOOP
          ;jmp     FAILURE





;Restore text mode
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h

;Return
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


;Color
;cX
;cY
;R
drawFilledCircle:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 sub sp, 02h

 mov cx, WORD [bp+04h]   ;R

 mov ax, cx              
 mul ax                  ;AX = R^2
 mov WORD [bp-02h], ax   ;[bp-02h] = R^2



 mov ax, WORD [bp+06h]
 sub ax, cx              ;i = cY-R
 mov bx, WORD [bp+08h]
 sub bx, cx              ;j = cX-R

 shl cx, 1
 mov dx, cx              ;DX = Copy of 2R

.advance_v:
 push cx
 push bx

 mov cx,  dx

.advance_h:
  ;Save values
  push bx
  push ax
  push dx

  ;Compute (i-y) and (j-x)
  sub ax, WORD [bp+06h]
  sub bx, WORD [bp+08h]

  mul ax                  ;Compute (i-y)^2

  push ax
  mov ax, bx             
  mul ax
  pop bx                  ;Compute (j-x)^2 in ax, (i-y)^2 is in bx now

  add ax, bx              ;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2
  cmp ax, WORD [bp-02h]   ;;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 <= R^2

  ;Restore values before jump
  pop dx
  pop ax
  pop bx

  ja .continue            ;Skip pixel if (j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 > R^2

  ;Write pixel
  push WORD [bp+0ah]
  push bx
  push ax
  call writePx


.continue:

  ;Advance j
  inc bx
 loop .advance_h

 ;Advance i
 inc ax


 pop bx            ;Restore j
 pop cx            ;Restore counter

loop .advance_v

 add sp, 02h


 pop bp
 ret 08h



;Color
;X
;Y
writePx:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 push ax
 push bx

 mov bx, WORD [bp+04h]
 mov ax, bx
 shl bx, 6
 shl ax, 8
 add bx, ax       ;320 = 256 + 64

 add bx, WORD [bp+06h]
 mov ax, WORD [bp+08h]

 ;TODO: Clip

 mov BYTE [es:bx], al

 pop bx
 pop ax

 pop bp
 ret 06h




times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; Fill the rest with zeros
dw 0xAA55  ; Boot loader signature
```